# azure function cannot read application setting using configurationManager or GetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've set some application settings in the azure function app but I'm getting null when I try to read them

```
System.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[name]

System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variableKey, System.EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

Both of them gave me null. I can get the value fine running on local where my settings are in local.settings.json

Comment: have you tried setting these appsettings in the ApplicationSettings of azure?

Comment: @MichaelHenderson that is exactly where I set them, I set them in the portal in app settings under application settings tab

Comment: If you go to Kudu Console (https://{app}.scm.azurewebsites.net) and click on Environment tab, do you see your env variables there?

Comment: I restarted the app and it solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(pulling the answers from the comments to aid in future searches)

1. When dealing with Appsettings, try restarting the app. (although normally the site would restart automatically when you change an appsetting)
2. You can use Kudu to verify the appsettings are indeed properly set on the site. (https://{app}.scm.azurewebsites.net) and click on Environment tab). They'll also show up as environment variables.